# How to run IE under different credentials?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, command-prompt, qtp

For automatic testing we want to use a VBScript which starts an instance of internet explorer and uses different credentials. When we visit our site, Windows credentials are used to validate the login (e.g., if you store the credentials in credential manager, you can login automatically). We want to do the same with VBScript :

```
Dim oShell
set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "RunAs /profile /user:[TheUser] ""C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
WScript.Sleep 100
oShell.Sendkeys "[password]~"
Wscript.Quit
```

This Script does login and start iexplorer, but when we visit the site it just asks for credentials as if nothing happened.

Does anyone know how to pass credentials to internet explorer (as if they were in the credential manager), and login automatically? (This would cut a significant portion of our time on the regression tests, since logging in via the popup screen takes very long.)

Comment: Are you able to logon to Windows using this account and then open IE without being asked for password?

Comment: The WScript.Sleep 100 could be replaced by a wait for the the dialog. This would cut upto 100 ms from the wait.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your internet explorer settings?  We set ours up to prompt every time the browser is opened so perhaps you're doing something similar?

This link shows how to achieve what we do:

http://randomtech.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-force-internet-explorer-to.html

So simply perform most of the steps then remove the forced prompt.  If your build machine does a teardown etc the initial login was still take time but from that point on it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately changing the prompt does not help since the flows use different users. Two logins are used every time. A login is necessary. The bottle neck is the popup during the login. We want it to be faster and that is why we are looking for a faster way to login. We know from experience that credential manager is faster (there might be more ways to login we are unaware of), we just don't have a way to do it in code.